# Write lines to a text file in python

Tags: python, xml, python-3.4

I have been trying to write a statement to an XML in python

I need to write the Following into the XML

```
  <SimBase.Document Type="Launch" version="1,0">
  <Descr>Launch</Descr>
  <Filename>dll.xml</Filename>
  <Disabled>False</Disabled>
  <Launch.ManualLoad>False</Launch.ManualLoad>
  <Launch.Addon>
    <Name>jb777 Panel Loader</Name>
    <Disabled>False</Disabled>
    <Path>Modules\jb777loader.dll</Path>
  </Launch.Addon>
  <Launch.Addon>
    <Name>jb777 fmc</Name>
    <Disabled>False</Disabled>
    <Path>Modules\jb777_fmc.dll</Path>
    <DllStartName>module_init</DllStartName>
    <DllStopName>module_deinit</DllStopName>
  </Launch.Addon>
</SimBase.Document>
```

How will I be able to write this to the XML

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Do you want to write exactly that, or do you want to fill in different bits of data later? If you just want the strung, your normal text editor would do.

Answer (score 3):

Creating and writing data to a file in python as easy as opening a file

```
file_obj = open("xml_file.xml", 'wb')
```

If you already having the data,

```
file_data = """<SimBase.Document Type="Launch" version="1,0">
  <Descr>Launch</Descr>
  <Filename>dll.xml</Filename>
  <Disabled>False</Disabled>
  <Launch.ManualLoad>False</Launch.ManualLoad>
  <Launch.Addon>
    <Name>jb777 Panel Loader</Name>
    <Disabled>False</Disabled>
    <Path>Modules\jb777loader.dll</Path>
  </Launch.Addon>
  <Launch.Addon>
    <Name>jb777 fmc</Name>
    <Disabled>False</Disabled>
    <Path>Modules\jb777_fmc.dll</Path>
    <DllStartName>module_init</DllStartName>
    <DllStopName>module_deinit</DllStopName>
  </Launch.Addon>
</SimBase.Document>"""

file_obj.write(file_data)
file_obj.close()
```

Comment: As I've seen in various other places, it is not a good practice to name the variable file because it can interfere with something in python (not sure what).

Comment: You need triple quotes for multi lined strings.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hanza\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\PythonApplication3\PythonApplication3\PythonApplication3.py", line 23, in <module>
    dll.write(file_data)
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface